# Why can't i scrape the particular Amazon music page with selenium python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[https://www.amazon.com/Prettymuch-EP-PRETTYMUCH/dp/B07CF6YXDP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CF6YXDP)

The pure above mentioned link, not the link that one is directed to once clicking on it with the stack overflow tag.

This is the url.

```
def get_soup(url):
headers = {'User-Agent':
           'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36',
           }
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
r.raise_for_status()
return BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

url = input("Please enter an Amazon music url:")
soup = get_soup(url)
```

I get an error when requesting through it, why is that so?

```
Please enter an Amazon music url:https://www.amazon.com/Prettymuch-EP- 
PRETTYMUCH/dp/B07CF6YXDP 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Pycharm (4)/selemin.py", line 4, in <module>
    import amazon
  File "D:\Pycharm (4)\amazon.py", line 63, in <module>
    soup = get_soup(url)
  File "D:\Pycharm (4)\amazon.py", line 12, in get_soup
    r.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
    packages\requests\models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
 requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: 
 https://www.amazon.com/Prettymuch-EP-PRETTYMUCH/dp/B07CF6YXDP%20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at what the error is telling you - it's a different url. In particular, it's throwing an error because it ends with `%20`. This means there was a space at the end of your input. I would recommend processing your input to avoid this, something like

```
new_url = url.strip()
```